# Is there any way to use Point Cloud Library (or similar) to get a skeleton from point cloud data like obj?

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

everyone.

I've been stuck for some days searching some way to get the skeleton of a point cloud data (like OBJ) but not using kinect. Is it possible?
I found the Point Cloud Library which does a lot of tasks related to point cloud data, and in their [documentation](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/gpu_people.php) there is a body keypoints detector, but it also works with kinect grabbers. 
In my case, I have a point cloud data like in the picture, which was generated by another depth sensor scanner. Is it possible to find the key points in such data?

I really would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it's not explicitly mentioned in the tutorial you linked, a quick to [the code](https://github.com/otherlab/pcl/blob/master/gpu/people/tools/people_app.cpp#L388) suggests that you can use different data sources (e.g. PCD files), so you're not stuck with the live capture from Kinect.

All the tutorial code really does is the following:

- [Setup the GPU](https://github.com/otherlab/pcl/blob/master/gpu/people/tools/people_app.cpp#L364-L368) for the people parts detection.
- [Pick](https://github.com/otherlab/pcl/blob/master/gpu/people/tools/people_app.cpp#L374-L407) the appropriate data source.
- [Load the tree files](https://github.com/otherlab/pcl/blob/master/gpu/people/tools/people_app.cpp#L410-L414) for the [body part detector](https://github.com/otherlab/pcl/blob/master/gpu/people/tools/people_app.cpp#L431-L433).
- Run the `PeopleDetector` on a [single frame](https://github.com/otherlab/pcl/blob/master/gpu/people/tools/people_app.cpp#L292-L295) captured from the live grabber stream/PCD file.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know there were these examples on their repository.